# Objective-C: Custom BOOL accessor (getter & setter) methods

Tags: objective-c, custom-attributes, boolean, accessor

I know someone already asked about [Writing getter and setter for BOOL variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099062/writing-getter-and-setter-for-bool-variable). But, if I'm defining a custom getter & setter methods `setImmediate` & `isImmediate`, respectively, I'd like `passcode.immediate = NO` to work too.

I do not have any instance variables, but maybe I should? I could add one for `NSDate *lastUnlocked`.

Here's the relevant code so far:

```
// PasscodeLock.h

extern NSString *const kPasscodeLastUnlocked;

@interface PasscodeLock : NSObject {

}

- (BOOL)isImmediate;
- (void)setImmediate:(BOOL)on;

- (NSDate *)lastUnlocked;
- (void)resetLastUnlocked;
- (void)setLastUnlocked:(NSDate *)lastUnlocked;

@end


// PasscodeLock.m

#import "PasscodeLock.h"

NSString *const kPasscodeLastUnlocked    = @"kPasscodeLastUnlocked";

@implementation PasscodeLock

#pragma mark PasscodeLock

- (BOOL)isImmediate {
    return self.lastUnlocked == nil;
}

- (void)setImmediate:(BOOL)on {
    if (on) {
        [self resetLastUnlocked];
    } else {
        self.lastUnlocked = nil;        
    }
}

- (NSDate *)lastUnlocked {
    return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kPasscodeLastUnlocked];
}

- (void)resetLastUnlocked {
    NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    self.lastUnlocked = now;
    [now release];
}

- (void)setLastUnlocked:(NSDate *)lastUnlocked {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:lastUnlocked forKey:kPasscodeLastUnlocked];
}
```

Then, in a view controller that has `PasswordLock *passwordLock` as an instance variable, I want to do `passcode.immediate = NO`, but I get the error "Property 'immediate' not found on object of type 'PasscodeLock *'."

How do I get `passcode.immediate = NO` to work?

Comment: Why your `-lastUnlocked` returns an NSString but `-setLastUnlocked:` takes an NSDate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue ids that your getter and setter names are not consistent.  By default, if you have

```
foo.immediate
```

in your code, [it is assumed](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW17) that the getter and setter are named `-immediate` and `-setImmediate:` respectively.  Your getter is not named correctly.  The *best* way around this is to declare a property as Mark and Kenny have already said but you *could* also change the name of your getter.

The point is that you do not *need* declared properties to use dot syntax, but if you are going to use dot syntax then declared properties are the recommended way of declaring the getter and setter.

Comment: Thanks. I just changed the name of the getter from `-isImmediate` to `-immediate`.

Answer (score 10):

You need something like

```
@property (nonatomic, getter=isImmediate) BOOL immediate;
```

in your .h file and of course a `@synthesize` statement in your .m file. This creates the property AND defines your getter method name.

Comment: The nonatomic part is redundant for an assign property.

Answer (score 8):

Declare such property in the @interface:

```
@interface PasscodeLock : NSObject {

}
@property(dynamic, getter=isImmediate,
                   setter=setImmediate:) BOOL immediate;
// etc.
@end
```

(The `setter=` part is optional)